# C++ template, ambiguous overload

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, operator-overloading

for some reason I have two classes implementing the operator "+" with templates,
(I do that because I want all children of those two classes to be able to use it).

I have come down to a very simple code implementing what I would like to use:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A{};

template<typename T>
A operator+(T& lhs,int rhs){
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "T must inherit from A");
  A to_return;
  return to_return;
}

class B{};

template<typename T>
B operator+(T& lhs,int rhs){
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<B, T>::value, "T must inherit from B");
  B to_return;
  return to_return;
}


int main()
{
  A u;
  A v = u+1;
}
```

When compiling, the compiler (g++ or intel) returns the following error :

- g++ : main.cpp:25:11: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+' in 'u + 1'
      main.cpp:25:11: note: candidates are:
      main.cpp:6:3: note: A operator+(T&, int) [with T = A]
      main.cpp:15:3: note: B operator+(T&, int) [with T = A]
- icpc : main.cpp(25): error: more than one operator "+" matches these operands:
       function template "A operator+(T &, int)"
       function template "B operator+(T &, int)"
       operand types are: A + int
  A v = u+1;
         ^

Although it is not that ambiguous as v should be of type A, so only the first template should work.

Any idea to get around this keeping the two templates operators ?

Or another idea to have an operator working for all children of A and B ?
I.e. for all classes C child of A, I would like to be able to write 
`A w = u + 1; //where u is of type C.`
And same for B.

Thank you,

Tony

## EDIT:

Following the answer given by Barry, std::enable_if does the job. However, it turns out that what I needed exactly was to use two typenames, the technique proposed by Barry has to be slightly modified to add this possibility:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class A{};

template<typename T1,typename T2 = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A,T1>::value, A>::type>
A operator+(T1& lhs,T2& rhs){
  A to_return;
  return to_return;
}

class B{};

template<typename T1,typename T2 = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<B,T1>::value, B>::type>
B operator+(T2& lhs,T2& rhs){
  B to_return;
  return to_return;
}


int main()
{
  A u;
  A w = u+u;
}
```

Then it works fine, even if T1 and T2 are different children of  A.

Comment: Just do not build template operators taking anything (I consider it a design flaw) - be more specific

Comment: *"Although it is not that ambiguous as v should be of type A, so only the first template should work." * Where'd you get that idea?

Comment: T can be any children of A (resp. B) for the first one (resp. the second one). If there is any way to tell that to the compiler, I am fine with this solution.

Comment: your static_assert is not an immediate context that could exclude overload from the overload resolution, did you try [SFINAE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30b6c361dcf98465)?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be ambiguous? Return type is not considered in resolution.

Comment: @jrok, from "A v = u+1;", as there is no suitable conversion between A and B, I think u+1 can only be of type A, and thus only the first template should compile.

Comment: @Tony Nope that's not how it works. There's overload resolution for `u+1` and, if that suceeds, conversion to A.

Comment: @Tony: this is not how the type system works, `u+1` exists in a context which is not linked to how it is used (or if it assigned at all to anything). The correct operator overload must be found regardless of the assignment.

Comment: @jrok,Jack. Thank you for the precisions.

Comment: @Piotr S. Seems like a good idea !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Overload resolution is solely based on the function *signature*, which is its name, its cv-qualifications, and its parameter types.

For your first one, that is:

```
operator+(T& lhs, int rhs);
```

And for your second one, that is also:

```
operator+(T& lhs, int rhs);
```

Since those are identical, the compiler can't distinguish between the two - hence the ambiguity. One way around this is to move your static assert into the return type and use SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<A, T>::value,
    A
>::type
operator+(T& lhs,int rhs){
    // stuff
}
```

And the same for your other operator. This will work until you try it with some `T` that derives from both, and then it will become ambiguous again.

Or, depending on what you're actually doing with `lhs`, simply:

```
A operator+(A& lhs, int rhs); // already accepts anything that derives from A
```

Comment: Here's a [working sample](http://ideone.com/rLEi6y) changing the code as recommended.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. 
And indeed, "A operator+(A& lhs, int rhs);" makes the job !